# difference between jpatemplate and jpadaosupport

Tags: spring, dao

What is the difference between JpaTeplate and JpaDaoSupport (Or similar version of HibernateTemplate and HibernateDaoSupport).

I read spring documentation and spring suggest not to use this any more. I am just curious to know what is the reason behind that. One reason I understand is decoupling between spring and persistence layer. But that can not be the only reason to remove this.

Can any one put some light on it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In earlier days the `*Template` made it easier to work with the underlying technology, this was especially the case in the days of hibernate2 and early hibernate3 releases. However all these technologies have progressed and the use of the `*Template` doesn't make much sense anymore. It only ties your data access layer to spring without any, real, added benefit. Hence the suggestion to not use it anymore but use the plain API (i.e. JPA or Hibernate directly).

The `*DaoSupport` classes do some bootstrapping and/or detection for you so that you can just call the `get*Template` method and get a ready to use `*Template`. Basically the `*DaoSupport` allows easy access to the configured `*Template` and saves you from constructing one yourself.

However as mentioned in the reference guide you shouldn't be using the templates and thus support classes anymore (the only exception being the JDBC version of those).

Comment: This is true for Hibernate/JpaTemplate. Others like JdbcTemplate are still valuable.

Comment: After reading bit more in detail, I came to know that these template classes convert hibernate exceptions into runtime spring's DataAccessException. If I dont use template classes, how will I get DataAccessException? and how about automatically closing sessions?

Comment: You still get that if you use annotation driven configuration you get this automatically (regardless the use or non-use of the Templates).

Comment: One more question. Earlier I was using below method to get instance of entitymanager in jpa. But without using jpatemplate, how will I get instance of entityManager? return (T) getJpaTemplate().execute(new JpaCallback() {
   public Object doInJpa(final EntityManager em) { .... }  (Sorry for unformmating. Not able to format the code.)

Comment: That is what dependency injection is for. I suggest you take a read of the spring reference guide, that explains al that.