# difference between JpaRepository and JpaDaoSupport?

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

There are some ways for us to implement JPA in Spring framework.
Is JpaRepository can be known as the spring data solution for JpaDaoSupport?

- `JpaDaoSupport` : from `org.springframework.orm.jpa.support`
- `JpaRepository` : from `org.springframework.data.jpa`

I think this is similar to **difference between jpatemplate and jpadatasupport** [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21506942/difference-between-jpatemplate-and-jpadaosupport)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`JpaDaoSupport`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.4.RELEASE_to_4.0.0.M3/Spring%20Framework%203.2.4.RELEASE/org/springframework/orm/jpa/support/JpaDaoSupport.html) class has been deprecated in Spring 3.1 and should not be used in new projects. More generally, the JPA template pattern has been deprecated in Spring 3.1 and should not be used anymore.

Read this article from Baeldung for details: [The DAO with JPA and Spring](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-dao-jpa)

You should now use [CrudRepository](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html), [JpaRepository](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaRepository.html), or [PagingAndSortingRepository](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/PagingAndSortingRepository.html).

Read [CrudRepository, JpaRepository, and PagingAndSortingRepository in Spring Data](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-repositories) for explanations.